# libv8 with ruby on FreeBSD 12

Tags: ruby, v8, freebsd, libv8

I'm trying to get a ruby app working on FreeBSD 12 but I seem to fail miserably.

I installed v8 via `pkg install v8` and tried to install the libv8 gem via this command:

```
gem install libv8 -v '7.3.492.27.1' -- --with-system-v8
```

This seems to work fine until it calls `gclient` which refuses to run on FreeBSD with

```
KeyError: 'freebsd12'
```

I search a lot but could not find any solution to the problem. Is there any way to get libv8 working on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments in [`this issue`](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/253) in [`libv8 repo`](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/) there are no binary gems for FreeBSD after version 6.0.

You could try to build from source or use downgraded version